# Does express-validator sanitize.escape() the same as DOMPurify?

Tags: node.js, express, xss, sanitization, express-validator

Want to take measures to protect myself against XSS.

Right now, I have:

```
sanitizeQuery('searchQuery').escape().trim()
```

Is that adequate protection? Or would you recommend adding something like DOM Purify (running on the node end) as well?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No

Long answer: your approach will get you most part of the way but and I quote:

> HTML entity encoding doesn't work if you're putting untrusted data inside a  tag anywhere, or an event handler attribute like onmouseover, or inside CSS, or in a URL.

You should be using something like [DOMPurify](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify)

Source [XSS Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dompurify`  with express-validator.

```
const { param, validationResult } = require('express-validator')
const createDOMPurify = require('dompurify');
const { JSDOM } = require('jsdom');

 const xssSenitize = (value) => {
    const window = new JSDOM('').window;
    const DOMPurify = createDOMPurify(window);
    return DOMPurify.sanitize(value, { ALLOWED_TAGS: [] });
  }

 query(['id']).customSanitizer(xssSenitize)
```